# Insert a json subdocument in a mongoDB document in python

Tags: python, json, mongodb

I want to insert a subdocument in a document that I have in my mongoDB database. I want to retrieve with a find a subdoc and then to add something there. My code for retrieving the document is the following:

```
db = client['database']
col= db['database_values']
res = col.find({"user_id": "13245"}) //returns the document after user_id which begins with item_id

temp = {"item_id": {"11": {"first_process": [],"sec_process": [],}}}
res.update(temp)  //this is not working
```

How can I insert the subdocument in the filtered json file returned after the find method with the res (cursor)? How am I going to add the temp_json to the res collection?

**EDIT**: I manage to add sub-documents by filtering the user_id. Now I want to do the same for the case of item_id. For the case of user_id:

```
collection.update_one({"user_id": "13245"},{"$set": {"Item.11.first_process": [], "Item.11.sec_process": []}})
```

How can I do the same for the case of user_id, to check if item_id exist (already did that) and if yes to just update the sub-sub-document:

```
collection.update_one({"user_id": "13245", "Item": {"11":{}}}, {"$set": {"string": "123"}}) // tried sth like that but did not work
```

My whole code is the following:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
collection = db['database']
res = collection.find({"User": "123"}) 
if res.count() == 0:
   print "zero"
   dss_historical_json = {"User": "123", "Item": {"123456": {"process1": [],"process2": [],}}}
   process1_json = {"timestamp": "21354879546213", "process1_value": 0.4, "state": {"B": 0.1, "F": 0.2, "E": 0.3}}
   process2_json = {"timestamp": "11354879546213", "process2_value": 0.2, "performance": 0.8}
   dss_historical_json["Item"][str(123456)]["process1"].append(process1_json)
   dss_historical_json["Item"][str(123456)]["process2"].append(process2_json)
   temp = db.historical_values
   temp = db.historical_values
   post_id = temp.insert_one(dss_historical_json).inserted_id
else:
   for line in res:
      counter = 0
      for key in line["Item"].keys():
         if line["Item"].keys()[counter] == "123469":
         collection.update_one({"User": "123"}, {"$addToSet": {"Item.123469.process1": [{"timestamp": "213546879", "process1_value": 1,"state": {"B": 0.1, "F": 0.2, "E": 0.3}}],"Item.123469.process2": [{"timestamp": "11354879546213","process2_value": 0.2,"performance": 0.8}]}})
         else:
             collection.update_one({"User": "123"},{"$set": {"Item.123469.process1": [{"timestamp": "213546879", "process1_value": 1, "state": {"B": 0.1, "F": 0.2, "E": 0.3}}],
                                                       "Item.123469.process2": [{"timestamp": "11354879546213", "process2_value": 0.2, "performance": 0.8}]}})
         counter = counter + 1
```

Comment: Use the `$set` operator in an update method as `collection.update_one({"user_id": "13245"}, {"$set": temp_json})`

Comment: I tried that, but the json remain the same. Nothing was added.

Comment: Actually it works by updating the values of the item_id. What I want to is to keep both the previous and the new one.

Comment: Your question is unclear. `res` is a `cursor` type object. your code should generate error. Also do you want to update the dictionary or update the document in database?

Comment: Try `collection.update_one({"user_id": "13245"}, {"$set": { "item_id.111111.first_process": [], "item_id.111111.sec_process": [] }})`

Comment: I want to update the document in the database. Actually i want to insert the temp_json into the filtered document after find (in the same document), so to have one document with one user_id and a lot of different item_ids.

Comment: The problem is that update_one just updates the document in the database with the lastest item_id. I want to keep all the item_id that I am using every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
collection.update_one({"user_id": "13245"},{"$set": temp_json})
```

As I can understand your issue, you want to insert multiple `item_id`. You can do it like this:

```
collection.update_one({"user_id": "13245"},{"$set": {"item_id.111111":temp_json.get('item_id').get('111111')}})
```

Check the documentation for inserting embeded documents: [Set Fields in Embedded Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#set-fields-in-embedded-documents)

Comment: This solution just updates my document with the last item_id that I am using. I want to keep track all the previous temp_json inside my database.

Comment: I tried to use instead of update_one insert but then it creates a new document from scratch for the same user_id.

Comment: there are multiple `item_id` for a single `user_id`?

Comment: Yes exactly. This is what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: With the use of insert instead of update_one i managed to create two docs with the same user_id. I want to have one doc for a unique user_id and for every different item_id a subdoc.

Comment: Yes. I understand. I am checking that.

Comment: Found it. Actually was the suggestion of @chridam with the dot.

Comment: Yes. That was it.

Comment: Actually I want one last thing. I want to add a check to see if item_id is already in the db and then to add the rest of the json in the same spiriti as in the case of user_id. It is bit more tricky here. How can I add the json?

Comment: Actually I want to create a code that every time i run it it will create new sub-sub- document  inside first_process and sec_process.

Comment: lets discuss in chat.